# Open Azure App Service in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-monaco

I am researching the process to upgrade an existing Mobile Service to an App Service Mobile App (is that redundant?).

I have created the App Service and am accessing its code files using Visual Studio Team Services "Monaco". I have implemented a small portion of the API and successfully connected it to a test iOS client.

Right now, I am trying to find a way to quickly and easily upload all of the table definition files (.json/.js) I need, rather than creating them manually in "Monaco" and editing them by hand. At this point, I have spent far more time researching than it would have taken to just add them by hand, but I'm stubborn.

Monaco gave me an option to "Open in Visual Studio Team Services" (or "Connect" or something like that), so I am giving that whirl, thinking that I could eventually connect Visual Studio 2015 to the repo for easier file manipulation.

After apparently successfully connecting the Monaco App Service to Visual Studio Team Services, **it's nowhere to be found!!!**

I can still see it in Monaco, and all of those functions appear to still be functional just fine, but on the Visual Studio Team Services side, I can't find it anywhere!

I tried disconnecting and re-connecting from the Monaco side to VS Team Services, but nothing changed.

So, I guess I have a couple of related questions:

1. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? VS Team Services appears to have some nice features, and I may indeed wish to use it, but I still like the ability to use a "thick" Desktop IDE to edit my code. For my Mobile Service, I connected WebStorm to the git repository and that worked nicely (especially for the files that wouldn't show up online!).
2. If I'm using the correct overall approach (create App Service, then connect it to VS Team Services, then download/link to VS Team Services from VS2015), what am I doing wrong and how can I get it to show up for me in VS Team Services?

Comment: Is your original code resource managed by version control in VSTS(VSO)?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the folder and select "Upload files" to upload your files from "Monaco":[image]

And you can also use [Kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console#upload-files-and-folder-using-drag-and-drop) to upload files to your App Service.

For connecting to Visual Studio Team Services, you have two choice after connecting to it (Perform it from "Git" tab):

1. Clone from Visual Studio Online: With this option, it will clone the source code from an exist project in your Visual Studio Team Services. You can pull the changes from VSTS or push the changes you made in Monaco back to VSTS.
2. Initial a new repository: You need to open the console and config the Git settings and add your VSTS remote repository. And then push the changes to remote repository, then you will see the files in Visual Studio Team Services.[image]